# Change colour depending on counter

Tags: color, counters

I have some text that I want to change colour depending on the current state of a counter. But I can't get this file to compile. (This is obviously simplified, since the texcolour command is actually part of a command defined in the preamble...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{30}
\begin{document}
\textcolor[RGB]{0,\value{foo},0}{Text in FOO colour}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error repeated:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \
l.8 ...r[RGB]{0,\value{foo},0}{Text in FOO colour}

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \
l.8 ...r[RGB]{0,\value{foo},0}{Text in FOO colour}
```

I'm sure there's some subtlety I've not grasped yet... But `\vskip \value{foo} pt` compiles fine and gives me space depending on the value of the counter, so I can't be far off...

Comment: The RGB model requires numbers between 0 and 1 for the components. So, I would not use a counter.

Comment: Actually, the `rbg` model requires numbers between 0 and 1.  The RGB model requires integers between 0 and `\rangeRGB`, which defaults to 255.

Comment: The actual command uses `red!\value{foo}!blue` . But as @Jan says, RGB uses numbers up to 255

Comment: Ah, I see. I just thought of the color package, but xcolor provides also that integer model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert `\the` before `\value`; then it works.

As to *why* you have to include `\the`: The culprit is `\@onelevel@sanitize` that is called inside `\XC@edef`. *What??* Let me try and explain. At some point, your `\textcolor` command makes the call

```
\XC@edef\@@clr{0,\value{foo},0}
```

This in turn calls

```
\edef\@@tmp{0,\value{foo},0}
```

(with some trickery regarding active characters), thus making `\@@tmp` contain `0,\c@foo,0` and *not* `0,30,0`: The `\edef` doesn't expand the counter `\c@foo` to it contents. Immediately after this, `\XC@edef` calls

```
\@onelevel@sanitize\@@tmp
```

which in turn expands to

```
\edef\@@tmp{\expandafter \strip@prefix \meaning \@@tmp}
```

And this does something horrible: It turns the 5 tokens `0,\c@foo,0` into the 11 tokens `0,\c@foo ,0`, i.e., the control sequence `\c@foo` is turned into a sequence of single characters (all with catcode 12, except the space). Now you've got your explanation for the strange error message

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \
```

The `\` is the first character of `\c@foo`! And it's not a number, indeed.

If you could follow up to this point, then it's easy to understand why `\the` helps out here:

```
\edef\@@tmp{0,\the\value{foo},0}
```

makes `\@@tmp` contain `0,30,0`, and no evil can happen anymore.

Comment: Though it _does_ work with `\the`, Stefan's comment to the question makes me wonder if my answer is stupid.

Comment: @Hendrik see the above comments on why it is not a stupid idea!

Comment: Also, could you explain why you need a `\the`? I thought `\value` expanded to the value, which is what you wanted for the argument for the colour command... I'm not sure I understand what's going on here

Comment: @Seamus: Well, that's a tough one. I got my answer just guessing, along the lines "Oh, let's see what happens if ...". I didn't include an explanation since I had none. It now took me ages to find it: I'll try and write something.

Comment: @Hendrik Thanks for the explanation! I can't say I fully understand it, but at least I know I wasn't missing anything obvious. I learned a new bit of TeX lore: if in doubt, try `\the`...

Comment: Good explanation! In my experience, things like this actually come up fairly often, and it is good to know what is happening.